# Как сделать так, что бы пользователю показывалось сообщение, если он перешел по несуществующему адресу? (на express или node.js)

Tags: node.js

Как сделать так, что бы пользователю показывалось сообщение, если он перешел по несуществующему адресу? (на express или node.js)

Comment: в примерах всё есть https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/error-pages/index.js

Comment: не могли бы уточнить, просто я тупой и не могу разобраться в том коде т.к начинающий